# Struct values being returned with unexpected results

Tags: c, pointers, struct, reference

I'm hoping someone can explain to me what exactly is happening here. I've got a much larger program I'm doing as an assignment but have broken out a portion of it that I can't seem to get to cooperate. This is my code:

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

#define MAX_LEN 80

struct my_struct
{
  char first_string[MAX_LEN+1];
  long first_string_len;
  char second_string[MAX_LEN+1];
  long second_string_len;
};

int main() {

  /*Initialize vars*/
  char first_word[MAX_LEN];
  char second_word[MAX_LEN];
  long first_word_len, second_word_len;

  /*take user input and add values to vars*/
  printf("first word: ");
  scanf("%s", first_word);
  printf("second word: ");
  scanf("%s", second_word);
  first_word_len = strlen(first_word);
  second_word_len = strlen(second_word);

  /*create struct*/
  struct my_struct word_pair = {*first_word, first_word_len, *second_word, second_word_len};

  /*Print results of variables*/
  printf("Variables\n%s is %ld characters long\n%s is %ld characters long\n\n", first_word, first_word_len, second_word, second_word_len);

  /*Print results of struct (expecting same output)*/
  printf("Struct\n%s is %ld characters long\n%s is %ld characters long\n", word_pair.first_string, word_pair.first_string_len, word_pair.second_string, word_pair.second_string_len);
}
```

I was expecting:

```
first word: hello
second word: world
Variables
hello is 5 characters long
world is 5 characters long

Struct
hello is 5 characters long
world is 5 characters long
```

but what I got was:

```
first word: hello
second word: world
Variables
hello is 5 characters long
world is 5 characters long

Struct
hw is 0 characters long
 is 0 characters long
```

Can someone explain to me exactly what's happening and how I should be passing these values?

Thanks for any help in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
 struct my_struct word_pair = {*first_word, first_word_len, *second_word, second_word_len};
```

this line is incorrect!

you cant assign `first_string` which is a struct member which is a char array with the dereference of other char array (`char first_word[MAX_LEN];`)!

`*first_word` will yield the first character in this array! Any you are trying to initialize characters array `my_struct.first_string` with character!

use `strcpy` to copy one char array to other one or the refered solution is to scanf directly to this char array (`my_struct.first_string`).

you can declare a struct variable and scanf to this variable (instead of calling strcpy):

**init the structure**

```
struct my_struct foo;
scanf("%s", foo.first_string);
scanf("%s", foo.second_string);
foo.second_string_len = strlen(foo.second_string);
foo.first_string_len = strlen(foo.first_string);
```

Comment: Ah that's perfect! Thanks very much! And thanks for such a quick reply.

Comment: @Cameron my pleasure. i would be glad if you vote it up (click the up arrow) and accept the answer (click the grey V nearby).